# How to set class of OrderingFilter's widget in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I want to set class of OrderingFilter's in Django framework.
I can add class to ModelChoiceFilter like that:

```
from django_filters import OrderingFilter, ModelChoiceFilter    

user_status_filter = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=UserStatus.objects.all(),
                                       label="Status",
                                       widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

But adding class to OrderingFilter results in error: 'ChoiceExactField.widget' must be a widget class, not <django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x000001FA0C6BCA48>'

```
order_by_filter = OrderingFilter(
    fields=(
        ('score', 'Score'),
        ('money', 'Money'),
    ),
    label="Sort by",
    widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
```

What is the proper solution to set class of this widget?

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with the same issue, and it seems like the OrderingFilter only accepts a widget class as a widget attribute.

An alternative would be:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select 
from django_filters import OrderingFilter
order_by_filter = OrderingFilter(
    fields=(
        ('score', 'Score'),
        ('money', 'Money'),
    ),
    label="Sort by",
    widget=Select
)
```

And then you can change the widget attributes after the widget is created, in the FilterSet init:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *, request=None, prefix=None):
    super().__init__(*args, request=request, data=data, **kwargs)

    order_by_filter = self.form.fields["order_by_filter"]
    order_by_filter.widget.attrs = {
        'class': 'form-control'
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing but didn't found any solution

You can try an alternative by using LinkWidget

```
from django_filters.widgets import LinkWidget
order_by_filter = OrderingFilter(
    fields=(
        ('score', 'Score'),
        ('money', 'Money'),
    ),
    widget=LinkWidget
)
```